# Writing a str and float into a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

For some reason I can't test my function. I get this error.

```
 print(write_avg(out_file('grades.csv')))
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 Python Shell, prompt 3, line 1
builtins.NameError: name 'out_file' is not defined
```

Can anyone please help me fix this? Here is my function.

```
 def write_avg(L, out_file):
  '''(list, file) -> NoneType
  Given a list of lists where each inner list consists of a string and a 
  float,and an open file for writing, write the contents of each inner list 
  as a line in the file. Each line of the file should be the string followed 
  by the float separated by a comma. Close the file when done.
  '''

for line in out_file:
    L.append(',')
    output_line = L
    out_file.write(output_line)
out_file.close()
```

Comment: The indentation in your code doesn't seem right.

Comment: You're missing an argument. Your function expect two arguments (i.e. L and out_file), but you only gave it L, thus 'out_file' was never defined in the scope because it was never passed in

Comment: You have out_file defined as both a parameter for `open()` and as a function in `print(write_avg(out_file('grades.csv')))`. This should not be.

Comment: So how could I fix this?

Comment: write_avg(list, 'grades.csv'). What is your desired output and example of input. A glimpse would help

Comment: you write in the description that `out_file` is an open file, then why are you opening it again ?

Comment: L.append(',')
builtins.TypeError: descriptor 'append' requires a 'list' object but received a 'str'
I get this error now, but I want to add a comma into the file

Answer (score 1):

```
def write_avg(L, out_file):


'''(list, file) -> NoneType
    Given a list of lists where each inner list consists of a string and a 
    float,and an open file for writing, write the contents of each inner list 
    as a line in the file. Each line of the file should be the string followed 
    by the float separated by a comma. Close the file when done.
    '''
    open_out_file = open(out_file, 'w')
    for y in L: # iterate over list
        result = y[0]+','+str(y[1]) + '\n'
        open_out_file.write(result) #format needed
        return result
    open_out_file.close()

gradeL = [['S',34],['A',34],['N',34],['L',34]]
write_avg(gradeL,'grades.csv')

Output in file:
S,34
A,34
N,34
L,34
```

Comment: I get my result horizontally when I print it. Did you call gradeL again after the write_avg statement?

Comment: Edited where were you printing from. gradeL is the parameter of write_avg. The function you defined needs two parameters.

Comment: so do I just type in write_avg(L, 'grades.csv')?

Comment: I get 'S, 34\n'

Comment: I only get the first inner list

Comment: post your code again, because on my side I am getting the output that is shown in the answer. Indentation could be the problem I fixed the code.

Comment: How would we do this using return

Comment: change print to return and make sure the return statement is the last line in the function

Comment: what are you trying to return a file, a list, a string

Comment: Do you mean the second last line?

Comment: Im trying to return a file

Comment: like returning it after writing something

Comment: Why, the file is created using python's open function? Do you mean to read it again after you wrote to it?

Comment: Oh ya my bad, I read the description again  and saw you wrote, it makes sense to me now.